# How to install tensorflow-gpu version 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had tensorflow-gpu version 2.0 installed in an environment and all worked fine. For some reason it stopped working. I created a new environment and executed conda install tensforflow-gpu. It installed version 2.4 development. This version has all sorts of warning and missing modules. How do I install tensorflow-gpu version 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtulenv,

You can either use,

```
conda install tensforflow-gpu=2.0
```

Otherwise, you can install it via pip within the venv as,

```
tensorflow-gpu==2.20
```

More information could be found over here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: tried conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.0  as you suggest, it installed however if I run the code to check the version it shows version 2.4. Yes I am in the new virtual environment which had no initial tensorflow version in it.

Comment: As tensorflow is downloaded by Conda it shows the version as 2.0.0 but that is not what gets installed. This is really strange.